# Computing $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t} \int_0^t f(t,t') \; \mathrm d t'$

Tags: integration

I understand that using the fundamental theorem of calculus, it is straightforward to compute
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\int_0^t f(t') \; \mathrm d t' = f(t).
$$
However, what if the integrand itself is also a function of $t$? How would one compute
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t} \int_0^t f(t,t') \; \mathrm d t'?
$$

Comment: I guess that chain rule for $f(t,t')$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider $\int_0^t f(t,t') \, \mathrm{d}t'$ as the composition of the two functions
$$F : (s,t) \mapsto \int_0^s f(t,t') \, \mathrm{d}t'$$
and
$$G : t \mapsto (t,t).$$
That is, $\int_0^t f(t,t') \, \mathrm{d}t' = F(G(t))$. Now apply the chain rule. As a result you get (a special case of) the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would you apply the chain rule in this case? Presumably $\frac{\mathrm d F}{\mathrm d t} = \frac{\mathrm d F}{\mathrm d G} \frac{\mathrm d G}{\mathrm d t}$, but $G$ is a pair of numbers and I don't understand how to carry out the calculation.

Comment: @ChrisYang You need to use the multi-variable chain rule: $\frac{\mathrm{d}(F \circ G)}{\mathrm{d}t}(t) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial s}(G(t))\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial t}(t) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(G(t))\frac{\partial G_2}{\partial t}(t)$.

Comment: Ah I see. Would it be simpler then to write $\frac{\mathrm d F(s(t),t)}{\mathrm d t} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial s}\frac{\mathrm d s}{\mathrm d t} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\frac{\mathrm d t}{\mathrm d t}$, where $s(t) = t$, without needing to reference $G$?

Comment: @ChrisYang That is correct, but to prove your formula from the chain rule, you would again have to introduce $G$.